# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\sqrt{a-b\cos t}}\mathrm dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

In the course of my research, I have stumbled upon the following integral, which I do not know how to compute:

$$I(a,b)=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\sqrt{a-b\cos t}}\mathrm dt,\qquad a>b>0.$$

Help would be greatly appreciated.

---

My thoughts on the problem:

1. Using the substitution $z=e^{it}$ yields a contour integral of a function analytic in some neighborhood of the circle $|z|=1$, so techniques from complex analysis might help.
2. For $a=b$, the function from the previous point has a singularity at $z=1$, but we have the following explicit result (found with some help from Mathematica): $$I(a,a)=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\sqrt{a-a\cos t}}\mathrm dt=2\pi(I_0(\sqrt{2a})-\mathbf{L}_0(\sqrt{2a})),$$ where $I_0$ and $\mathbf{L}_0$ are modified Bessel and Struve functions, respectively.
3. Alternatively, using the substitution $s=\sqrt{a-b\cos t}$ and exploiting the fact that the original integrand is symmetric about $t=\pi$, we obtain the following expression for the integral: $$I(a,b)=\int_{\sqrt{a-b}}^{\sqrt{a+b}}\frac{4s e^{-s}\mathrm ds}{\sqrt{b^2-(a-s^2)^2}},$$ however I also do not see how to proceed from here.

Comment: $I(a,b)=\mathcal{L}_s\left[\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{4 s}} \sqrt{\pi } I_0(b s)}{s^{3/2}}\right](a)$ where: $ I_0(b s)$ is modified BesselI.

Answer (score 3):

I will attempt to gain some results using a form similar to elliptic integrals.

First, we use the symmetry to change the limits:

$$I(a,b)=2 \int_0^{\pi}e^{-\sqrt{a-b\cos t}}\mathrm dt$$

Then we use the following substitutions:

> $$u=\sin \frac{t}{2},\qquad q=\sqrt{a+b},\qquad p=\frac{2b}{a+b}$$

We get another form of the integral:

> $$I(a,b)=4 \int_0^1 \frac{\exp (-q \sqrt{1-pu^2})}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \mathrm du$$

While it looks even more complicated, it has some uses. For example, in the simple case considered by the OP, $a=b$ and thus $p=1$, we can expand the exponential function to get:

$$I(a,a)=4 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{q^n}{n!} \int_0^1 (1-u^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \mathrm du=2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{\pi }~ \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)} \frac{q^n}{n!}$$

This series can be shown to give the closed form from the OP, since $q=\sqrt{2a}$.

---

In general, let's expand the exponential function and get the series:

$$I(a,b)=4 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{q^n}{n!} I_n$$

Where:

$$I_n=\int_0^1 (1-u^2)^{-1/2} (1-p u^2)^{n/2} \mathrm du$$

Numerically, this doesn't make sense, as the convergence of the series is extremely slow.

However, we can find the closed form for the integrals, substituting $u^2=v$:

$$I_n=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 v^{-1/2} (1-v)^{-1/2} (1-p v)^{n/2} \mathrm dv$$

But this is just Euler integral for Gauss hypergeometric function, so:

$$I_n=\frac{\pi}{2} {_2 F_1} \left(-\frac{n}{2}, \frac{1}{2};1; p\right)$$

So we get a series representation:

> $$I(a,b)=2 \pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n ~{_2 F_1} \left(-\frac{n}{2}, \frac{1}{2};1; p\right)~ \frac{q^n}{n!}$$

For rational $p$ hypergeometric functions usually have a closed form. For even $n$ and any $p$ they can be represented as polynomials, which follows from the properties of hypergeometric series.

---

Using the hypergeometric series and changing the order of summation allows us to obtain another series for the integral, in terms of so called [Bessel polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_polynomials).

I don't have the time to provide the details of the calculation (I used some help from Mathematica to guess the result), but we have a very nice series:

> $$I(a,b)= \sqrt{8 \pi q}~ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2 k)! ~ K_{k-\frac{1}{2}}(q)}{ (k!)^3} \frac{p^k q^k}{8^k}$$

Where $K_{\alpha}(q)$ is the modified Bessel function, and in this case it gives polynomials multiplied by exponential function (see the Wikipedia link).

Numerical experiments confirm these results.