# $\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{b^m }{(m!)^2}K_{m+\frac{1}{2}}(a)$ with Bessel K

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

How can this expression reformulated without sum or integral? $K$ is a modified Bessel function of the $2^{\text{nd}}$ kind with positive half-integer order. Due to the squared factorial the sum converges very quickly.

\begin{align*}\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{b^m}{(m!)^2}K_{m+\frac{1}{2}}(a)& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi  a}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\exp  \left(\frac{2b}{a(t^2+1)}+i a t\right)}{t^2+1} \, {\rm d}t\\ & =\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-a \cosh(t)} e^{-\frac t2}\bigg(\text I_0\big(2\sqrt be^{-\frac t2}\big)+e^t\text I_0\big(2\sqrt be^\frac t2\big)\bigg){\rm d}t,
\end{align*}
with $a$, $b>0$ and $i$ being the imaginary unit.

The last expression contains Bessel ${\rm I}_0$ functions and was derived in the post [below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4341283/737314). An integral-free and sum-free representation is still missing.

The Bessel $K$ function can be expressed as a finite sum however then one has to deal with a double sum.
$$K_{m+\frac{1}{2}}(a)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2 a}} \frac{1}{e^a}\sum _{k=0}^m \frac{(m+k)!}{k!(m-k)!}\frac{1}{(2a)^k}$$

Comment: The fact that the $ab$ is written that way is irrelevant, that can just be $b$ at no loss for "outsiders".

Comment: Have you checked out the classic tables? Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, Prudnikov, Bateman, etc. The pre calculator era of applied math holds some gems... Infinite series of Bessels are a common target for analysis. What happens if you insert the summation form for $K_m(a)$ and change the order of the sums... any progress? What about an integral representation and swapping the integral with the sum? Those are things to try

Comment: @granularbastard You can still change the order of summation, you just need to account for that dependence when doing so. A cute way to work it out: draw $m = 0, 1, 2, \dots, $ and $k = 0, 1, \dots, m$ in the plane with an $m$-axis and a $k$-axis. You're then summing over an infinitely large "triangle", *column by column*. Changing the order of summation simply means summing over the same "triangle", but this time *row by row*. (Or vice versa with rows/columns; depends on which axis is $m$ and $k$.)

Comment: Can you give some motivation about why you care about this particular series?

Comment: @granularbastard Never write things like $i=\sqrt{-1}$ because it is ambiguous. The complex square root is multivalued.

Answer (score 2):

Let’s try to find a solution using an integral representation of [Bessel K](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/07/01/01/0002/):

$$\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{b^m }{(m!)^2}\text K_{m+\frac{1}{2}}(a)= \sum _{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{b^m }{(m!)^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-a \cosh(t)}\cosh \bigg(\bigg( m+\frac12\bigg)t\bigg) dt$$

The inside is a Bessel K sum with $\text{Re}(a)>0$ with term by term integration:

$$\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{b^m }{(m!)^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-a \cosh(t)}\cosh \bigg(\bigg( m+\frac12\bigg)t\bigg) dt =\int_0^\infty e^{-a \cosh(t)}\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{b^m }{(m!)^2}\cosh \bigg(\bigg( m+\frac12\bigg)t\bigg) dt =\boxed{\frac 12\int_0^\infty e^{-a \cosh(t)} e^{-\frac t2}\bigg(\text I_0\big(2\sqrt be^{-\frac t2}\big)+e^t\text I_0\big(2\sqrt be^\frac t2\big)\bigg)dt}$$

Which works as seen with [this $a=4,b=2$ case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+2%5Em%2Fm%21%5E2+besselK%28m%2B1%2F2%2C4%29+from+0+to+4000+-integral+exp%28-4+cosh%28t%29%291%2F2+e%5E%28-t%2F2%29+%28BesselI%280%2C+2+sqrt%282%29+e%5E%28-t%2F2%29%29+%2B+e%5Et+BesselI%280%2C+2+sqrt%282%29+e%5E%28t%2F2%29%29%29+from+0+to+infinity) with the [Bessel I function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) Sorry if this is not a closed form, but now you can try to evaluate the above integral. The integral seems to have no closed form for special cases of $b,a$ and there is no way I see to put it into a general hypergeometric form. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Also see:

> [Evaluating the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\sqrt{a-b\cos t}}\mathrm dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609154/evaluating-the-integral-int-02-pie-sqrta-b-cos-t-mathrm-dt?noredirect=1)

Where a very similar sum is the result for the integral, but no closed form was provided in the answer by @Yuriy.